# Add user to group based on their attribute department with Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory, attributes

I was struggling with this for a while so will be really glad if someone could help me with this :)

The idea is:
We have  users with the filled department attribute (ex. LCZ_10960-udrzba rezie, LCZ_40900-financni utvar, etc...)
and we have created security groups that look like CZ-udrzba_rezie_10960, CZ-financni_utvar_40900, etc...
And that what I want from the script is to search through specific OU for users and check their department attribute and if they have forex. LCZ_10960-udrzba rezie in it then add this user to group CZ-udrzba_rezie_10960 or if another user has CZ-financni_utvar_40900 in the department then add this user the group LCZ_40900-financni utvar...

Hope I explain it good :)

I already create the script but that is only for
add single group...
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "XY,DC=local" -Filter 'Department -like "UK_12345_marketing"' | Foreach{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "GRP_UK_12345_marketing" -Members $_}

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: please, add code formatting to your Question. right now it is needlessly hard to read. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it like this:

1. Pull all the group names for validation
2. Pull all users with their `department` attribute values
3. Loop through all users and validate + add to the corresponding group

```
# Fetch all groups:
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'GRP_*'" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Fetch all users:
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Department -like '*_*_*'"

# Loop over the users
foreach($user in $users){
    $targetGroupName = "GRP_$($user.department)"
    if($groups -contains $targetGroupName){
        # Corresponding group exists, let's add
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $targetGroupName -Members $user
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself exactly..
I wanted to outline it but actually, the name convention is slightly different.
The groups are like CZ-technology_12345 or CZ-Project_management_18468(there are plenty of other groups with the same prefix which I don't want to deal with) (and there is not every time the same amount of words in the name of the group(don't know if that's a problem or no)) 
Do you have a different idea of how to deal with this?
Perhaps we can do like translation table with names of groups and names of departments for which that script can reach.

Comment: @Skyller Please update your question with the actual naming conventions :-)

Comment: OK :)
Name of groups 
CZ-udrzba_rezie_10960
CZ-rezie_svarovani_14409

Name of departments:
LCZ_10960-udrzba rezie
LCZ_14409-rezie svarovna
etc....

Comment: @Skyller Please [update your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66172626/edit)